# What is the difference between implicit constructors and default constructors?

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor, explicit-constructor

This is very trivial, but Czech language (my native) doesn't distinguish between implicit and default, so I am confused by some Czech translations what is the difference between implicit and default constructor or constructor call.

```
struct Test {
  Test(int n=0) { }
};
```

Can you describe in these terms what the following statements do?

1. `Test t1;`
2. `Test t2();`
3. `Test t3 = 3;`
4. `Test t4(4);`
5. `Test t5 = Test(5);`

Comment: I would recommend that you use C++ (technical books in general) in english when possible.

Comment: I do. The problem is, that my native language confuses *implicit* and *default* in my mind, it is mostly linguistic issue. Besides the coding skills I need to change the language of thinking too - which is quite exciting challenge.

Comment: I doubt that the translation is the same since the meaning is quite different in English. Default is often translated as _výchozí_, while implicit as  
_implicitní_ meaning something like _nevýslovný_. (disclaimer: I know Czech only a little)

Comment: @RomanShapovalov that could be exact translation, but *nevyslovený* has also other misleading meanings in Czech, so it's often translated semantically or (perharps better) not at all.

Comment: The English words "implicit" and "default" do not cleanly describe the natures of these constructors. These words are labels, and as programmers we must learn what actual C++ behavior they correspond to. If the designers of C++ had assigned these words the other way around, our job would not have been much different.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The terms *default* and *implicit*, when talking about a constructor have the following meaning:

- **default constructor** is a constructor that can be called with no arguments. It either takes no arguments or has default values for each of the arguments taken.
- **implicit constructor** is a term commonly used to talk about two different concepts in the language, the

  - *implicitly declared constructor* which is a *default* or copy constructor that will be declared for all user classes if no user defined constructor is provided (default) or no copy constructor is provided (copy). That is, a class with no constructors declared by the user has one *default constructor* implicitly declared.
  - *implicitly defined constructor* is a *implicitly declared constructor* that is used (*odr-used*<sup>1</sup> in the language and for which the compiler will provide a definition.

  ```
  struct test
  {
      test(int i = 0) { }
      // test(test const&) implicitly declared here
  };

  struct test2 { };      // implicitly declared: test2(), test2(test2 const&)

  int main()
  {
      test t;

      test copy(t);      // causes *definition* of the implicitly
                         // declared copy constructor

      test2 t2;          // causes *definition* of test2::test2()

      test2 copy2(t2);   // causes *definition* of test2::test2(test2 const&)
  }
  ```

In simple terms, a constructor is *default* if it can be called with no arguments. A constructor is *implicit(ly declared/defined)* if it is not provided by the user but declared/defined.

As of the specific cases:

```
Test t1;
```

Uses the default constructor, `Test(int = 0)`, which is not implicit.

```
Test t2();
```

This is a strange quirk of the language, it declares a function that takes no arguments and returns a `Test` object.

```
Test t3 = 3;
```

This is called *copy-initialization* and is equivalent to the composition of an implicit<sup>*</sup> conversion from `3` to `Test` and copy construction of `t3` from the result of the conversion. This will use the `Test(int)` constructor for the conversion, and then the *implicitly defined* (and *declared*) copy constructor. Note: the compiler can optimize away the copy, but it must verify that the copy constructor is available (access specifiers) and can be defined.

```
Test t4(4);
```

Uses the `Test(int)` constructor, which in this case is not acting as a *default* constructor.

```
Test t5 = Test(5);
```

Equivalent to the `Test t3 = 3` case, with the only difference that the conversion from `5` to `Test` is explicit in this case. In this example it won't matter, but if the constructor had been marked as `explicit` this line would compile while the `t3` case would fail.

---

*) Yet another use of *implicit*, in this case referring to the fact that the conversion from `3` to `Test` is not explicitly requested in the code. Compare this with `t5` where the conversion is explicitly requested by the programmer: `Test(5)`.

Comment: @Leonid: the term is formally defined in the standard, but in effect it means that something calls it or otherwise requires it to exist.

Comment: And then, as if there weren't enough implicit constructors, we also have aggregate initialization for aggregate types :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712872/what-is-aggregate-initialization

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be confusing some of the terms. A **default** constructor is one which takes no parameters, an **implicit call** is when you directly call the constructor.

Anyway:

> 1) Test t1;

Default constructor.

> 2) Test t2();

Function declaration.

> 3) Test t3 = 3;

Copy initialization. Will call the conversion constructor, create a temporary `Test` from `3`, and use the copy constructor to create `t3`.

> 4) Test t4(4);

Direct initialization. Uses the conversion constructor directly.

> 5) Test t5 = Test(5);

Copy initialization. Similar to 3).

Comment: Which of 1-5 is implicit call then?

Comment: @JanTuroň I'd say 1) and 3). Note that 2) doesn't call the constructor at all.

Comment: C++ Primer Plus Czech edition claims that 4) is implicit call. Is it translation error?

Comment: @JanTuroň could be (and seems like a mistake), but how is implicit/explicit defined? In 4), to me it looks like you're *expplicitly* calling `Test(int)`.

Comment: I am not sure. The book says that 4) is implicit call, 5) is explicit call and there is nothing about 1) and 3). 5) is definitely explicit. I've seen on multiple places 1) and 3) reffered as implicit. But I am still confused about 4)

Comment: @JanTuroň nonetheless, implicit & explicit are, in this case, use informally, so it largely depends on what the authors mean by the terms.

Comment: Surely the fifth and third would be *move* initialization now, since `Test(5)` is an rvalue.

Comment: @DeadMG: Not according to the language specification... §8.5/13 *The initialization that occurs in the form `T x=a;` [...] is called **copy-initialization***

Comment: It might be named that, but I think that it's still a misnomer when moving might be the Standard-mandated result.