# is there a way to initialize members in brace?

Tags: c++, initialization

I have a class DealSchedule with some members defined, now I have to initialize it with something like:

```
DealSchedule trf_schedule;
trf_schedule.site_ = site;
trf_schedule.deal_id_ = deal_id;
trf_schedule.payment_date_ = payment_date;
trf_schedule.ccy1_ = ccy1;
trf_schedule.ccy2_ = ccy2;
```

Is it possible to write nicely as

```
DealSchedule trf_schedule 
{ 
  site_ = site;
  deal_id_ = deal_id;
  payment_date_ = payment_date;
  ccy1_ = ccy1;
  ccy2_ = ccy2;
};
```

this would protect changes to the initialization.

I can come out with something like this (need c++14 supporting renaming in lambda capturing):

```
DealSchedule trf_schedule;
[&_=trf_schedule]()
{
  _.site_ = site;
  _.deal_id_ = deal_id;
  _.payment_date_ = payment_date;
  _.ccy1_ = ccy1;
  _.ccy2_ = ccy2;
}();
```

Comment: You only have 5 members to initialize, why not make it a part of the constructor? So you could call it like `trf_schedule = { site, deal_id, payment_date, ccy1, ccy2 };`

Comment: trying to avoid updating constructors as the member list grow. @Fireboyd78

Comment: Ah, I see. Well unfortunately there's not really a way to do it the way you want to in C++, and your best bet would be to use a constructor overload.

Comment: Do your design first, that will reduce "as the member list grows" effort

Comment: "trying to avoid updating constructors as the member list grow." - what about destructors?

Comment: You may be able to take advantage of Aggregate Initialization. [What is Aggregate Initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712872/what-is-aggregate-initialization) Click the link and find out if Aggregate Initialization is right for you!

Comment: @FKEinternet i live in a world keeps growing.

Comment: @iehrlich destructor is not an issue as such are POD classes,or rather, structs.

Comment: @user4581301 it works for struct but without "calling the names of the class/struct members', so the 1-1 relationship is only ensured by the sequence, this is unsafe.

Comment: Yup, but it's that or a constructor, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is R_Sahu's, but in the event you really want that syntax and are feeling self-destructive...

```
struct _ : public DealSchedule { _() { 
  site_ = site;
  deal_id_ = deal_id;
  payment_date_ = payment_date;
  ccy1_ = ccy1;
  ccy2_ = ccy2;
}} trf_schedule;
```

This uses an inline struct for initialization, which you can then slice back to a `DealSchedule`.

(Don't actually do this)

Comment: *and are feeling self-destructive* Nice to see some light hearted content :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DealSchedule trf_schedule 
{ 
  site_ = site;
  deal_id_ = deal_id;
  payment_date_ = payment_date;
  ccy1_ = ccy1;
  ccy2_ = ccy2;
};
```

is not valid C++ syntax to initialize an object. You can initialize the object using

```
DealSchedule trf_schedule = {site, deal_id, payment_date, ccy1, ccy2};
```

if

1. The corresponding members are `public` (which sounds like is true in your case) and no other explicit or user defined constructors are provided, or
2. There is a constructor that takes those arguments.

Comment: 1. [...] and no other explicit or user defined constructors are provided