# Defining Scope in C++ OOP Program

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to get better at C++ by challenging myself by creating a program that manages employees. Given a certain salary vs. sales you will either be hired, fired or keep your job. I have been working with OOP a lot recently and thought that structuring it by class would make the exercise easier. I've gone over this again and again and I can't seem to find a solution. That being said I would very much appreciate some insight on what I am doing wrong. Keep in mind I am new to C++ and OOP but the more I learn the better I will be in the future.

Originally it was all one file then I separated the classes into header files. It seems to run a little smoother now but I still get the error that name, salary and scope (my variables) aren't defined in the scope of my program.

```
main.cpp

#include "Boss.h"
#include "Employee.h"
#include "PotentialEmployee.h"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


int main ()
{


  Boss Boss1;
  Boss Boss2;
  Boss Boss3;

  Employee Employee1;
  Employee Employee2;
  Employee Employee3;

  PotentialEmployee PotentialEmployee1;
  PotentialEmployee PotentialEmployee2;

  Employee1.name = "Michael";
  Employee2.name = "John";
  Employee3.name = "Lisa";

  Boss1.name = "Luke";
  Boss2.name = "Ben";
  Boss3.name = "Jack";

  PotentialEmployee1.name = "Bill";
  PotentialEmployee2.name = "Fred";

  Employee1.salary = 55000;
  Employee2.salary = 65000;
  Employee3.salary = 75000;

  Boss1.salary = 88000;
  Boss2.salary = 95000;
  Boss3.salary = 88000;

  PotentialEmployee1.salary = 55000;
  PotentialEmployee2.salary = 65000;

  Employee1.sales = 12000;
  Employee2.sales = 40000;
  Employee3.sales = 80000;

  Boss1.sales = 200000;
  Boss2.sales = 250000;
  Boss3.sales = 280000;

  PotentialEmployee1.sales = 55000;
  PotentialEmployee2.sales = 65000;


  if (sales <= salary) 
    std::cout << "I'm sorry " << name << "you have been fired";

  else if (sales >= salary) 

      std::cout << "Good job " << name << "you get a bonus";

   else 
      std::cout << "Try and do better next quarter";


      return 0;
    }
```

> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: main.cpp:66:7: error: ‘sales’ was
>   not declared in this scope if (sales <= salary) { ^ main.cpp:66:16:
>   error: ‘salary’ was not declared in this scope if (sales <= salary) {
>   ^ main.cpp:67:34: error: ‘name’ was not declared in this scope
>   std::cout << "I'm sorry " << name << "you have been fired"; ^
>   main.cpp:71:35: error: ‘name’ was not declared in this scope std::cout
>   << "Good job " << name << "you get a bonus";

Comment: Can you please include the exact error you get?

Comment: 1) "_I still get the error that name, salary and scope (my variables) aren't defined in the scope of my program._" Please copy-paste the error-message, instead of paraphrasing it. 2) Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Where *are* `name`, `salary`, and `scope` declared? They are not declared in this code. (You're not using anything called "scope". Did you mean "sales"?)

Comment: I apologize, i'm new to StackOverflow and it only let me include the main file. Let me add the rest.

Comment: Here are my exact errors: main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:66:7: error: ‘sales’ was not declared in this scope
   if (sales <= salary) {
       ^
main.cpp:66:16: error: ‘salary’ was not declared in this scope
   if (sales <= salary) {
                ^
main.cpp:67:34: error: ‘name’ was not declared in this scope
     std::cout << "I'm sorry " << name << "you have been fired";
                                  ^
main.cpp:71:35: error: ‘name’ was not declared in this scope
       std::cout << "Good job " << name << "you get a bonus";
                                   ^

Comment: Name, salary and scope are declared in the individual header files. They all follow this format. #include <iostream>
#pragma once 


using namespace std;

struct Boss
{

public:
  string name;
  int salary;
  int sales;
 
  
};

Comment: you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55419729/edit) your question. I added the error message for you, but the formatting is horrible, maybe you can fix that.

Comment: @JordanBrandes Those are member variables. You've been assigning values to them, and examining their values looks exactly the same: `Boss1.sales <= Boss1.salary`. Perhaps it's time for a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: I see no `sales` defined anywhere in the given code. Presumably you have `Boss::sales` and `Employee::sales`, but no `sales`.

Comment: Got it! Thank you guys for your help! I was hoping to do it in a more general way where I wouldn't have to write out Boss1, Boss2, Boss3 each time but it looks like that's the best way to do it.

Comment: Sidenote: When you have numbered variables, it usually means you want an array. `Boss Bosses[3];` and later `Boss[0].name = "Luke";`. Also read up on [aggregate initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712872/what-is-aggregate-initialization). It's very handy stuff.

Answer (score 2):

As the error tries to tell you there is no `sales` and no `salary` declared in `main`. You probably want to refer to the `Employee`s `sales` and `salary`, that would be

```
if (Employee1.sales <= Employee1.salary) 
    std::cout << "I'm sorry " << name << "you have been fired";
```

Some more tips:

- better use small starting letters for object names and capitals for types. In your code it is not easy to see what is a variable and what is a type.
- whenever you find yourself naming variables `foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3` etc you should use a `std::vector` or an array instead. This will help you to loop over all employes and evaluate their sales/salary.
- the `{}` for `if` and `else` are optional, but it is often better to write them any way.
- your two cases are not exclusive. If `sales == salary` then both conditions would be true, but only the first one will get evaluated. Hence there is a tiny confusion: Looking at the `else` condition one might expect that a employee with `sales == salary` did a good job, but they will get fired :(
- last and least, a company that keeps their employess even if they generate zero income is a very nice one :)

PS:

> I was hoping to do it in a more general way where I wouldn't have to
>   write out Boss1, Boss2, Boss3 each time but it looks like that's the
>   best way to do it

When you find yourself writing a block of code that has lots of `Boss1.some_member` then that block of code is a good candidate to be actually implemented in a member function (where you dont need to prefix the object). Eg the employee could have a `bool Employee::evaluate_salary_vs_sales();` that contains the logic you now have in main and returns whether they get fired or not.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. As I said i'm new and the more guidance I have the better I'll be in the future. I'll edit my code in the future.

Comment: @JordanBrandes glad to help, though you should take what I wrote with a grain of salt, SO is not the best place for tutoring and my answer is lots of handwaving. For proper learning there is no way around getting a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)