# C++ : Understanding implicit typecasting for classes with a constructor with 1 argument

Tags: c++, class, implicit-conversion

Would appreciate clarification on what exactly is happening when a constructor has only one argument and it is said that it does an implicit cast to the class type - right there It is confusing to me because :

```
class dog {
public :
        dog(string name) {    mname = name;}
private :
         string mname;
};
```

I don't understand how a type string can be converted to a type dog, I can see how it can be passed in and SET another string but if a string is converted to type dog what would that even mean? Would it be type dog that gets assigned a bit wise copy of a string?

Comment: Possibly you are looking for this :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340257/default-vs-implicit-constructor-in-c

Comment: Note that the title of the question I linked to doesn't match up, but the accepted answer covers implicit typecasting perfectly. (Like NathanOliver's answer, really.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class dog { 
public: 
    dog(std::string name) : mname(name) {} // use initializer list
private: 
    std::string mname;
};

void Foo(dog g) {}

int main()
{
    std::string name = "fido";
    Foo(name);
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2dd530c3780812a3)</kbd>

What this is doing is the comiler see's that you are calling `Foo()` but instead of giving it a `dog` we are giving it a `string`.  So the compiler goes "Okay,  Is there any way I can make a dog from a string?  Lets look at the `dog` constructors.  Oh look,  I can construct a `dog` from a `string`.  I will go ahead and make a `dog` from the `string` you passed to `Foo()` and everything will be okay."

This is what is called an implicit type cast.  We can prevent this from happening by marking the constructor as `explicit`.  Making a constructor `explicit` removes it from being used in implicit conversions

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class dog { 
public: 
    explicit dog(std::string name) : mname(name) {} // use initializer list
private: 
    std::string mname;
};

void Foo(dog g) {}

int main()
{
    std::string name = "fido";
    Foo(name);
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cefe8e537c401f92)</kbd>

Now the compiler goes through the same steps but it can't use the constructor so you will get an compiler error.  Now if we want the conversion we would manually have to do it like:

```
Foo(dog(name));
```