# Strange QString initialization with 0 - what does it do?

Tags: c++, qt

Sorry, but I can't find a right place in C++ manual.

In a following string:

```
void setYRange(QString name1, int s1, int e1, QString name2 = 0, int s2 = 0, int e2 = 0);
```

I do not understand the initialization:

```
QString name2 = 0
```

- If it is a string, why it is initialized with an integer?
- If it is an object reference, why it isn't initialized with NULL ?
- If it creates an object and fills it with 0 bytes, how does it know how much bytes to allocate?

Please give me just a reference to the right place in C++ manual.

Comment: You might look herer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340257/default-vs-implicit-constructor-in-c) for further reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the compiler choosing the [`QString::QString(const QChar *unicode, int size = -1)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-1) constructor.  `0` is the null pointer value so a pointer can be implicitly constructed from it.  That means to  compiler will chose the c-string constructor and initialize the pointer to a null pointer.  Since the pointer is null and that means you will construct an null `QString`(it is empty).

Do note that this behavior is different from a `std::string`.  Constructing one of those from a null pointer is undefined behavior.

Comment: Does it mean that this 0 will be used as the first parameter of the constructor and not as a value of an object self?

Comment: @Paul Yes.  `unicode` is initialized to `0`(null) and size stays `-1`.

Comment: `QString::QString(const QChar *unicode, int size = -1)`  is explicit. Here another constructor is used.

Comment: @Meefte Looks like they changed that between versions.  Look like prior to version 5x it was not.  If they are using the 5x version it might be using `QString::QString(QChar ch)`