# Correct way to signal QObject on another thread?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Let's say I have a `slave` object that lives in another thread. I want to tell it to do A, B, C on that thread. I can think of 3 ways of doing it:

(1) Using `QTimer::singleShot`

(2) Using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`

(3) Creating another `master` object and connecting its signal to the `slave`

Following is an example:

```
class slave : public QObject
{
    QThread thread_;

    friend class master;
    void do_A(params);
    void do_B(params);
    void do_C(params);

public:
    slave() { thread_.start(); moveToThread(&thread_); }
    ~slave() { thread_.quit(); thread_.wait(); }

    void que_A(params) { QTimer::singleShot(0, [&](){ do_A(params); }); } // (1)

    void que_B(params) { QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "do_B", params); } // (2)
}

class master : public QObject // (3)
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    master(slave* s) { connect(this, &master::que_C, s, &slave::do_C); }

    void do_C(params) { emit que_C(params); }

signals:
    void que_C(params);
}
```

My concerns are:

(1) I am abusing `QTimer`.

(2) Using strings for signals/slot is so qt4. Qt5 uses [new syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).

(3) Too much boilerplate.

Is any of the methods considered more correct compared to the others? Or can anybody think of a better way?

Please include your reasoning (not just opinion) why one method should be chosen over others.

**UPDATE**:

In my real-world application I have another class -- let's call it `owner` -- that owns several `slave`s. The `owner` needs to tell different `slave`s to do different things (A, B or C) depending on user input. The `slave`s are stateful objects, so I cannot see an easy way of using concurrency functions (eg, `std::async` or `QtConcurrency`).

Comment: moveToThread(this)? Are you sure it is correct? It should even not compile...

moveToThread is waiting for a QThread* and not a QObject...

Comment: Moreover, you are not using at all your QThread but in your destructor ^^

Comment: @AntoineMorrier I guess the compiler makes an implicit construction of QThread from QObject

Comment: Yeah, but no. his slave class inherits a QObject class and not a QThread. So this must not compile. A QThread is a QObject, but a QObject is not a QThread.

Moreover, admit he wanted to inherits a QThread, move to thread(this) is WRONG and WRONG

Comment: @AntoineMorrier I am not saying using moveToTread(this) makes sens. I was (wrongly) thinking that the compiler would perforn an [implicit construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340257/default-vs-implicit-constructor-in-c). After reflexion, you're right this would not compile.

Comment: @AntoineMorrier sorry, typo

Comment: @InnocentBystander Yes, so it is a problem ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I will not comment (1) and (2) but I must say that (3) is the one usually used. However, I understand your concern about too much boilerplate. After all, creating a separate signal, say `doActionA()`, connecting it via `QueuedConnection` to some real `actionA()` and at last emitting it... too much noise and useless moves.

Indeed, the only benefit it gives you is a loose coupling (you can send a signal being not aware of existence of slots connected to it). But if I create a signal with a name `doActionA()` **of course I am aware** of `actionA()` existence. So then the question is starting to raise "Why do I have to write all this stuff?"

Meanwhile, Qt kind of provides the solution to this problem giving you the ability to post your own events to any event loop (and as you know QThread has one). So, implement it once and you do not need to write a lot of `connect` `emit` stuff any more. Also, I suppose I is more efficient because all in all, every slot invokation via `QueuedConnection` just posts an event in an event loop.

Here `InvokeAsync` posts the event for member function execution into the event loop of the thread where QObject lives:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QThread>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

template<typename T, typename R, typename ... Params, typename... Args>
void InvokeAsync(T* object, R (T::*function)(Params...), Args&&... args)
{
    struct Event : public QEvent
    {
        std::function<R ()> function;
        Event(T* object, R (T::*function)(Params...),  Args&& ... args)
            : QEvent{ QEvent::None },
              function{ std::bind(function, object, std::forward<Args>(args)...) }
        {
        }
        ~Event() { function(); }
    };

    QCoreApplication::postEvent(object, new Event{ object, function, std::forward<Args>(args)... });
}

struct Worker : QObject
{
    void print(const std::string& message, int milliseconds)
    {
        QThread::currentThread()->msleep(milliseconds);
        std::cout << message
                  << " from thread "
                  << QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    std::cout << "GUI thread " << QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;

    QThread thread;
    thread.start();

    Worker worker;
    worker.moveToThread(&thread);

    InvokeAsync(&worker, &Worker::print, "Job 1", 800);
    InvokeAsync(&worker, &Worker::print, "Job 2", 400);
    InvokeAsync(&worker, &Worker::print, "Job 3", 200);

    a.exec();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
GUI thread 00000000000019C8
Job 1 from thread 00000000000032B8
Job 2 from thread 00000000000032B8
Job 3 from thread 00000000000032B8
```

As you see all jobs where done in a different thread in order of their invocation. Qt guarantees that events with the same priority are processed in order as they were posted.

Also it is OK, if `worker` lives in GUI thread. Events will be just posted in GUI event loop and processed later (that is why I called those `Async`).

If you see any mistakes or have some remarks, please, write in comments and we will figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I am not pretty sure I understood well the question.
So I will explain here how to manage thread in Qt (in summarized way).

First, `QThread`class is not really meant to be inherited from.
Instead, make something like this :

```
class Slave : public QObject {
    Slave(QThread *thread) {moveToThread(thread);)
};

QThread thread;
Slave slave(&thread);
```

After, you normally can use signal and slots in the normal way.

However, if your objective is only to "run a function inside another thread", maybe QConcurrent could be a better way?

Comment: Regarding the multithreading alternatives, there is an excellent guide in the Qt documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html

Comment: I know how to move object to another thread. I guess my question wasn't very clear -- I will update it.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) provides a very nice example that probably answers your question on how to use QThread. It's the following:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void doWork(const QString &parameter) {
        QString result;
        /* ... here is the expensive or blocking operation ... */
        emit resultReady(result);
    }

signals:
    void resultReady(const QString &result);
};

class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread workerThread;
public:
    Controller() {
        Worker *worker = new Worker;
        worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
        connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
        connect(this, &Controller::operate, worker, &Worker::doWork);
        connect(worker, &Worker::resultReady, this, &Controller::handleResults);
        workerThread.start();
    }
    ~Controller() {
        workerThread.quit();
        workerThread.wait();
    }
public slots:
    void handleResults(const QString &);
signals:
    void operate(const QString &);
};
```

The idea here is simple. You have a worker, which is running in the thread. You also have the controller, which is basically your main thread that submits work to the other thread. The thread will (thread-safely) emit the `resultReady()` signal when it's finished. Signals and slots are thread-safe here, as long as they use [`Qt::QueuedConnection`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html) to communicate.

Comment: In an effort to keep my question from becoming TL;DR, I think I've oversimplified it. Basically your answer is good, but in my case the Controller has many Workers and each Worker has several signals. I need to be able to tell a specific Worker to do a specific thing. If the Controller has a unique signal for each slot in each Worker, they will start adding up. <Sigh...> Let me revise my question

Comment: @InnocentBystander Please explain why our answers still don't provide the answer you're looking for. I.e., what exactly is the problem you're foreseeing.