# Practical difference between implicit and defaulted constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

As far as I know, in C++ default constructors are declared (and defined if needed) implicitly if there is no user-defined default constructors. However, a user can declare a default constructor explicitly with the `default` keyword. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340257/default-vs-implicit-constructor-in-c) the answers are mainly about the difference between the *implicit* and *default* terms, but I didn't see an explanation about whether there is some difference between declaring a constructor as `default` and not declaring it at all.

As an example:

```
class Entity_default {
    int x;
public:
    Entity_default() = default;
}

class Entity_implicit {
    int x;
}
```

In the example above, I declare a constructor for `Entity_default` as `default` and let the compiler declare a default constructor implicitly for `Entity_implicit`. I assume I do call these constructors later on. Is there any difference between these constructors in practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no functional or theoretical difference, both are still "trivial."

Uses of an explicit default constructors:

1. To ensure it exists when it would not otherwise be created, i.e. if a different constructor exists
2. You can default it in a different compilation unit:

Header file:

```
struct Foo
{
    std::string bar;
    Foo() noexcept;
    ~Foo();
};
```

Source file:

```
Foo::Foo() noexcept = default;
Foo::~Foo() = default;
```

Useful if you don't want an inline constructor to save code size or ensure ABI compatibility. Note that at this point, it is no longer a trivial object.